# C++: Enforcing a function so it cannot accept any parameter that is passed by value

Tags: c++, function, c++11, c++14

How would you define and declare a function that would just **not** accept any parameter that get passed by value, in C++.
Like the following should return an error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function declaration
void swap(int &x, int &y);

int main () {
   // local variable declaration:
   int a = 100;
   int b = 200;

   cout << "Before swap, value of a :" << a << endl;
   cout << "Before swap, value of b :" << b << endl;


   swap(a, b); //This call MUST NOT be valid.


   int &x = a;
   int &y = b;
   swap(x,y); // This one should be valid.

   cout << "After swap, value of a :" << a << endl;
   cout << "After swap, value of b :" << b << endl;

   return 0;
}

void swap(int &x, int &y) {
   int temp;
   temp = x; /* save the value at address x */
   x = y;    /* put y into x */
   y = temp; /* put x into y */

   return;
}
```

in line `swap(a, b)` arguments are passed by value. I want it to return error when done like this.

**Update**

I was asked this question in an interview. To define a method which that returns an error when it gets called by values.

Like in above `swap` function call in main `a` and `b` must be references.

Comment: By declaring the function to not accept its argument by value? Can you please elaborate? What is the actual problem you want to solve? What is your use-case? What are you trying to accomplish with this? And what have you tried so far? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Parameters that are to be passed by reference are "marked" with an `&` (denoting a call by reference). Isn't it that what you are looking for?

Comment: "in line swap(a, b) arguments are passed by value." Eh ... no, they aren't?

Comment: Now when we see some example code, you *don't* pass the arguments to `swap` by value. You have declared `swap` as taking its arguments by reference, which means the compiler will pass `a` and `b` by reference. Otherwise the function would not work ([and it *does* work](http://ideone.com/HkITeE)).

Comment: Oh and I assume you're making your `swap` function as an exercise, since otherwise you should be using [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: Yes but I want to ensure that compiler don't do that. I want it to return an error something like `You are passing values to a function that only takes references`.

Comment: But you *don't* pass "values". You pass *references* to the variables `a` and `b` to your `swap` function.

Comment: Maybe you should try and explain what ***you*** mean by "passing references". You have shown us code that you think should give errors, but how *would* you like the function to be called?

Comment: @LifelongNoob if you tried to actually pass by value, like `swap(100, 200)` the compiler would complain.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that the variables you use in the call must *themselves* be references? If I may come with a suggestion: In the code you show add a comment on the `swap(a, b)` line saying that this call should not be valid, then *add* two new variables that *are* references (say `c` and `d`), and call `swap` with them, adding a comment that this call should be okay. That should make it much more clear about your intentions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was asked this in an interview. Interviewer asked me to give function such a definition that it should just return an error.  The above code should only work when `int & x = a`  `int &b = b` and call `swap(x, y);` It should return an error when called like `swap(a,b);`. I was stumped.

Comment: @LifelongNoob: Perhaps the question was asked to check how you cope with a request that they knew you wouldn't be able to fullfil.

Comment: did the interviewer ask you the question specific with `void swap(int &x, int &y)` or just say it? since you could still define two fuctions like `void swap(int x, int y)` (error) and `void swap(int* x, int* y)` (enforce pointers to use reference).. but I don't know if that would be good practice at all...

Comment: Are you sure the interviewer didn't mean to forbid calls with *rvalues*? Like e.g. `swap(100, 200)`? To check if you knew the difference between lvalues and rvalues? Because there's really no way of making `swap(a, b)` invalid while at the same time allow `swap(x, y)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, I suppose you can make it work if you make `swap` a macro...

Comment: I suspect you misunderstood what the interviewer was asking.  Because at this point, we only have the story of someone who couldn't answer the question remembering what they couldn't answer; broken telephone game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

```
int a{};
int& b{a};
```

then you cannot declare or define a function `foo` in a way that makes

```
foo(b);
```

compile while

```
foo(a);
```

does not compile/work.

If foo is declared like `foo(int& c)` then upon calling `foo` the compiler will bind the reference `c` to object `a` - no matter whether you passed `a` or `b` because the reference `c` can bind to any non-const, non-volatile lvalue of type `int`.

Within the scope of `a` and `b` both are lvalues an from the point of C++ there shouldn't be a difference in the call to `foo` because that's what references are about: They are just some kind of "named alias" to the original object.

Defining the function `swap(int&, int&)` already prevents "call by value".
The term "call by value" vs. "call by reference" refers to a property of the function paramter not of the passed object.